# Where to find a number-pattern based IQ test?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I'm asking this question in response to [this article](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2102577/A-genius-born-New-programme-intelligent-96-cent-humans-IQ-150.html). The article claims that a computer program has been created that scores 150 on a number-pattern based IQ test. I can find no such test online, has anyone heard of one? I would like to test my own program, which currently answers 6 of 8 questions correctly [on this test](https://www.fibonicci.com/numerical-reasoning/number-sequences-test/easy/), but it doesn't give me an IQ.

Math-based patterns are ideal, like: 1 4 10 22
Not stuff like this: 1 2 1 3 1 4 1

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on kaggle. They have have all kind of machine learning datasets and challenges. For example [this](https://www.kaggle.com/c/integer-sequence-learning) sounds like something similar to what you are looking for.